# Помогите с уникальными классами для кнопок html/css (пожалуйста)

Tags: javascript, modx

Смотрите, есть три товара, уникальных и разных. Допустим это телефоны. Каждый товар имеет свою цену, фото, описание и так далее. Необходимо сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку Buy, открывалась форма заказа. Я пытался сделать через id, прописал каждой кнопке одинаковое id, и прописал в JS при нажатии на кнопку Buy, чтобы появлялось всплывающие окно с формой заказа, но оно всплывает только у первого товара. Форма заказа у всех одинаковая, меняется только название/фото/цена/описание. Как сделать так чтобы у каждого товара она открывалась, а именно у каждого товара был свой id, чтобы человек добавляя товар через CMS, не знающий html/css/js не прописывал каждому товару свой класс. Буду благодарен за помощь!

---

[image]

Comment: не надо писать каждой кнопке одинаковый id. По id всегда возвращается только первый элемент.

Comment: Так, а как тогда?) Я же описал. Что если человек который не знает js/html/css будет добавлять товары через cms, как они будут срабатывать. Если нечему прописывать им id.

Comment: кроме id есть еще и классы, вот они могут быт одинаковы у множества элементов

Comment: Окей, допустим. У всех одинаковые классы, будет открываться форма заказа где должно быть фото, описание, название и цена товара. Как добиться этого, если одинаковые классы? В cms modx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ваш вопрос имел больше архитектурный характер.**

```js
let createModalWindow = (smth1, smth2) => { //функция создания окна подтверждения
let div = document.createElement('div'); //создаем <div>
let bttn = document.createElement('input'); //создаем <input>

div.style.border = "1px solid Black"; //css стиль div
div.innerHTML = `<p> Подтвердите покупку ${smth1} и ${smth2} </p>`; //вставляем текст в див, используя указанные в контструкторе объекта имена 
document.body.prepend(div); //вставляем див в body

bttn.setAttribute('type','button'); 
bttn.setAttribute('value','Подтвердить');
div.append(bttn); //вставляем кнопку в див

bttn.onclick = () => div.remove(); //удаляем элемент по клику кнопки в окне подтверждения
}

class Item { //каждая карточка продукта - класс
constructor(name, smth) { //конструктор карточки
 this.name = name; //1 имя
 this.smthElse = smth; //2 имя
}

createItem() { //функция создания html разметки
let div = document.createElement('div'); //создаем div
let img = document.createElement('img');//создаем img
let text = document.createElement('p'); //создаем <p>
let bttn = document.createElement('input'); //создаем <input>

div.classList.add('wrapper'); //добавляем класс карточке
document.body.append(div); //добавляем на страницу див карточки

//img.setAttribute("src", "YOUR LINK"); //тут картинка, но закоменчено, так как нет ссылки
//img.styles.width = "100px";
//div.append(img);

text.innerHTML = `${this.name} ${this.smthElse}`; //текстом карточки являются переданные в контруктор имена
div.append(text);

bttn.setAttribute('type','button');
bttn.setAttribute('value','click!');
div.append(bttn);

bttn.onclick = () => createModalWindow(this.name, this.smthElse); //по клику на кнопку вызываем функцию создания окна подтверждения
} 
}

let item = new Item('каблучки','макияж'); //создаем карточку 1
item.createItem();

let item1 = new Item('Шорты','куколки'); //создаем карточку 2
item1.createItem();

let item2 = new Item('шлепки','утопки');
item2.createItem();
```

Comment: Подскажи, что тут что означает?) + тут нет html кода, это тьма, c html можете переписать?

Comment: @Влад боюсь, чистый html не удовлетворит твои потребности

Comment: @Влад покрыл все коментами для удобства

Comment: От души за помощь)